# Google map Activity

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I want to use map activity in my application, I don't know how to deal with Google Map API v2.

How to generate an API key and All? Right now my application is not working with normal intent code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,GeoMap.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Android manifest entry like this

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".HomeTab" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GeoMap" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: have you add mapview in .xml file .?

Comment: If my link helped you,you should mark that as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Before asking something I think you should check the FAQ.
When you ask something ask Google first,it should give you some answer.

Anyways check this step by step tutorial for MAP API V2: [Google Maps API v2 for Android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

And for obtaining an API Key this simple tool might help you:
[JavaKeytoolGUI Beta 2](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/JavaKeyToolGUI.shtml)

Comment: The tutorial assumes Android 4.2, but I'm targeting Android 2.3, which I'm pretty sure does not have the Fragment class.  I don't see a Google API V2 tutorial that addresses this problem.

Comment: Okay do this,it might help you,target for 4.0/4.2 and set minSdkVersion to 2.3;this should work fine.Try and let me know.